# How to import WAR file using Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, jar, jersey, war

I'm working on a web service based on `Jersey`. This service is depended on several `Jar` files I wrote and complied seperately.
In one of those `Jars` I want to implement some `unit test`.
The thing is that the depended Jar is depended also on a data structure  declared in the service, as you can see in the diagram:

[image]

I want to import the WAR file into the Jar's project, so I can use the data structure declaration, and basically use the WAR as a `Driver` (in terms of Unit Tests), and test `ProcessStuff`.

By the way, I'm using `Gradle` build tool and dependency management.

Al

Comment: Did I understand you correctly: your war-project depends on some jar-projects and you want some of this jar-project depends on the war-project? It seems to become circular dependency. You rather have to move your data structure declarations into some common dependency for jar- and war-project.

Comment: You understood correctly. But for such cases on one project depends on another one, when you want to perform some tests you implement a stub or a driver, depends on the case. Here I want to use the WAR as a driver.
I agree its wrong to use a circular dependencies, but I do it only for testing.